# How to discover the currently active twig template

Tags: 8, theming

I need to find out the currently active Twig template from within my module preprocess function.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
    // How do i retrieve the currently active Twig template?
}
```

I need to know whether it is `field.html.twig`, `field--field-example.html.twig` or some other template suggestion.

Is that possible?

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: I'm creating a helper module for TailwindCSS theme.  I want to provide the themer with the ability to inject classes into fields without having to override every single template.  The idea is that the themer can create a YAML file containing a structured list of classes that I will load in the preprocess and inject.

Comment: Why would you need the template file name to decide which classes to inject? Wouldn't it make more sense to base it on criteria, like the field name, formatter being used, and so on?

Comment: I want to allow the themer to create a YAML file like this: https://ibb.co/6rJmwRF  Then in my module preprocess, I want to load the YAML file, check whether there is an entry matching the current Twig template and inject the classes.

Comment: I'm thinking that there must be somewhere in Drupal that determines the currently active (highest priority) twig template for a given field but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I thought that `theme_get_registry()` might help but it shows all template suggestions with no indication of the highest priority template.

Comment: Oh ok, you can get most of what you need from `ThemeManager::render()`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I'll check it out and post an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Clive's comment, I managed to identify the active theme suggestion.  Code below.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $theme_suggestions = mymodule_get_theme_suggestions($hook, $variables);

  $active_suggestion = mymodule_get_active_theme_suggestion($theme_suggestions);
}

function mymodule_get_theme_suggestions(String $base_hook, array $variables) {
  // Invoke hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
  $suggestions = \Drupal::moduleHandler()->invokeAll('theme_suggestions_' . $base_hook, [$variables]);

  // Invoke hook_theme_suggestions_alter().
  $hooks = [
    'theme_suggestions',
    'theme_suggestions_' . $base_hook,
  ];
  \Drupal::moduleHandler()->alter($hooks, $suggestions, $variables, $base_hook);

  array_unshift($suggestions, $base_hook);

  return $suggestions;
}

function mymodule_get_active_theme_suggestion($suggestions) {

  $theme_registry = theme_get_registry(FALSE);

  // Order by most specific first.
  $suggestions = array_reverse($suggestions);

  foreach ($suggestions as $candidate) {
    if ($theme_registry
      ->has($candidate)) {
      return $candidate;
    }
  }
}
```